# Can we use angular 6 in ionic 4 stable?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m in the process of migrating Ionic 3 application to ionic 4.0.0 and my current angular version is 6.

Can we upgrade to Ionic 4 without upgrading to Angular 7?

Reasons for sticking with Angular 6:
* We have few components which depends on Angular 6
* Our code base is so huge that we couldn't complete the migration on time.

I couldn’t find any minimum requirement information or documentation, hence reaching stackoverflow to help me with the relevant information.

Comment: Downvoting without any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ionic 4.0.x is compatible with angular 6. Ionic 4 was built with angular 6 through its alpha and beta stages. Eventually there may be a major version update that requires angular 7 due to breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you have any reference for the information as I asked in my question ?

Comment: You can look at the ionic release history and view the package.json, beyond that I don’t think it’s documented in their site, only mentioned within discussion. Ionic 4 was in beta/rc well before angular 7 was released.